# Which way should I put pens in a container: pointing up, or down?

Tags: office-layout

On my desk, I have a ceramic container with pens in it. I would like to know which way is more appropriate, pointing the pens up or down.

If the pens are pointed down, it would be "safer", but it would risk ruining the pens and damage the container. If the pens are pointed up, it wouldn't ruin the pens, but it would also be safety hazard.

Comment: if you seriously worry about the inside of the cup or pencil holder, use the lid. This is the only purpose of the lid, so fulfill it! When you throw out pens, save the lids for later use on lidless pens.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Disclaimer: it wasn't me. I agree the question itself is clear - but what I'm struggling to see is why anyone might spend time worrying about it. It's up there with "should I walk on the cracks between carpet tiles or not?"

Comment: Also not downvoter, but I'm struggling to see "workplace" here. What's next, paper clip storage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't specific to navigating the workplace as outlined in the help centre.

Comment: Dear Abby, Dear Abby
My fountain pen leaks http://www.lyricsfreak.com/j/john+prine/dear+abby_20074810.html

Comment: Another vote for off topic here.  I'm struggle to think of anywhere that might work as a migration endpoint.  Lifehacks would be a stretch; nothing else seems even vaguely in the right area.

Comment: How is this NOT about the "workplace"? Almost every workplace I've ever worked in, SOMEBODY has a pencil holder. It's not like a question about pencil holders naturally leads people to think of the kitchen or the playground. If there's a rule against questions that are trivial, that would be a valid objection. But "not about the workplace" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I store pens with the point down, because for many pens, if you store them point up, the ink runs down and then they don't write.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere And over-handed or under-handed. This is a multi-faceted issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It differs depending on the pen you are using:

> - **Felt tip pens** like whiteboard markers, Sharpies, Microns and    highlighters are best stored with the tip down. It keeps the ink in contact with the fiber/felt tip so that it does not dry out.
> - **Rollerballs** and **ballpoints** are best if they are stored upright so    they don’t leak or get gummy at the point.
> - **Gel pens** seem to be okay stored either up or down.
> - **Fountain pens** seem to like to be stored horizontal which keep the ink    in contact with the nib but doesn’t let gravity get too sassy.

[(Source)](http://www.wellappointeddesk.com/2013/07/ask-the-desk-storing-pens-up-or-down/)

Comment: When you say upright for ball points do you mean tip up ro tip down? My experience has been if they are tip up for any period of time the ink leaks out of the bottom (usually into a pocket; grrr)

Comment: +1 Modern fountain pens don't care which way they're stored, but older ones are best stored upright, so there's no risk of leakage (faulty feeds etc.). Since most FP inks are generally not very viscous, getting them to start again is easy (provided the ink hasn't gone dry). But then again if you own a decent fountain pen (or two, or three) you probably know how to store it

Answer (score 10):

Store all pens with the point down.

While it's not ideal for every pen type, it works for well enough for most. Almost nobody is going to use three or four different storage mechanisms in order to optimize their "pen storage effectiveness quotient".

Most of the pens will be paid for by your employer, as you indicate point-down is safer, and life is way too short to be worrying about the "best" way to store pens.

Comment: I prefer ballpoint pen stored point-down because the ball doesn't seem to dry out like it does when the point up.

Comment: Nobody is going to use three or four different storage mechanisms in order to optimize their "pen storage effectiveness quotient". -- Wanna bet?

Answer (score 2):

Store pencils with the point up. This way you will know which ones are nice and pointy, and which ones need sharpening. (And be careful with the pointy ones, so you don't poke yourself.)

Comment: Stated question is pens not pincels